# Матрицы преобразования в шейдерах OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm

Пишу под линукс на c++, библиотеки glfw, glew, glm. Столкнулся с проблемой, когда пытался передать матрицы в вершинный шейдер. Код полностью:

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "uniform mat4 model;\n"
    "uniform mat4 view;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}";

const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}";


int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    
#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (GLFWkeyfun)processInput);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
   
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }



    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        // Positions          // Texture Coords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // Top Right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom Left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // Top Left 
    };
    GLuint indices[] = {  // Note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3, // First Triangle
        1, 2, 3  // Second Triangle
    };
    GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // TexCoord attribute

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO


    
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glm::mat4 model;
        glm::mat4 view;
        glm::mat4 projection;
        model = glm::rotate(model, -55.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
        projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)SCR_WIDTH / (GLfloat)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        std::cout << view.length;
// Get their uniform location
        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
        GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"); 
        // Pass them to the shaders
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        // Note: currently we set the projection matrix each frame, but since the projection matrix rarely changes it's often best practice to set it outside the main loop only once.
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection)); 

        glBindVertexArray(VAO); 
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        // glBindVertexArray(0); // no need to unbind it every time 
 
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
    }


    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Вот тут вершинный шейдер (виден лишь пустой фон без фигуры)

```
const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "uniform mat4 model;\n"
    "uniform mat4 view;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}";
```

При подмене на:

```
const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "uniform mat4 model;\n"
    "uniform mat4 view;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}";
```

Все работает как надо, но понятно что матрица преобразования не применяется. Не знаю с чем это может быть связано, вроде как другие операции с векторами работают. Возможно что-то с glm, но я устанавливал новую версию.
Вот еще линковка:

```
g++ main.cpp -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw
```

У меня действительно нет идей на данный счет, возможно ошибка действительно в glm, но как это проверить я не знаю.

Comment: Я понял что ошибка определенно в glm, т.к. обычное перемножение матрицы трансформации (vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)) c вектором (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) дает результат:
9.75441e-30
9.18327e-41
2.22672e-08

Comment: Нет, ошибка определенно в вашем коде, подозрительно, что матрицы (неиницилизированные?) подаются на вход чтобы их инициализировать. `model = glm::rotate(model,`

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я сам это только что понял)

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно было заглянуть в мануал. Видимо с момента написания learnopengl glm успел обновиться и теперь для инициализации матрицы нужно:

```
        glm::mat4 model(1.f);
        glm::mat4 view(1.f);
        glm::mat4 projection(1.f);
```

Ну и плюс в функциях преобразования выразить градусы в радианах:

```
glm::radians(float);
```

После этого все заработало.

Comment: Правильнее будет не производить ненужную инициализацию единицами, а сразу инициализировать нужным значением `auto projection{glm::perspective(...)};`